# How do I access headers within a controller function in LoopBack?

Tags: http-headers, loopback

I have a function in loopback which uses it's very own special form of authentication.  I don't want to have this authentication stage done separately from the endpoint itself.  I would like to do my authentication within the endpoint code.

In order to do this, I need to access the Authorization header.

How can I do this within a loopback controller function?

```
  @get('/item/{itemId}', {
    description: `Get a specific item`,
    responses: {}
  })
  async getItem(
    @param.path.string('itemId') itemId: string,
  ): Promise<LabResult[]> {
    // How do I get headers from here?
    const auth = somehowGetHeaders().get("Authorization");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the headers by injecting the request object. For example . . .

```
@get('/item/{itemId}', {
  description: `Get a specific item`,
  responses: {}
})
async getItem(
  @param.path.string('itemId') itemId: string,
  @inject(RestBindings.Http.REQUEST) private req: Request
): Promise<LabResult[]> {
  console.log('headers', req.headers);
  // using header information here you can authenticate
}
```